# How to change the way selection is drawn on a image in a TListView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listview, selection, delphi-7

I load icons from exe/dll/ico and I display them in a TListView set to vsIcon. The images are stored in a TImageList set as TListView.LargeImages.
So each item in TListView is an image + a small text below.
The user selects one or more and clicks on a button.
The problem is that the selection of the images looks "ugly":

[image: 1]

I want to be drawn like on the desktop when you select a shortcut:

[image: 2]

But I need that TListView to have the same "behavior" in other situations. I say this because I know that using OnCustomDraw events is generating problems in other "areas".
And since the images are available only at runtime I can't store them in resources as "selected". But I think I can "double" the images from TImageList, if it's necessary.

Is it possible..?
Thank you.

PS: I use Delphi 7.

Comment: afaik, explorer draws such effects using alpha blending

Comment: @Downvoter Yes, I know. Is it possible to do the same with normal Delphi components or should I have to use external like TBitMap32?

Comment: Sounds like you mean that faint dash-line box around the image, correct? In this case, if you insist on removing this, you have no choice but to implement your own custom drawing completely from scratch. Too much code for me to put an example, but you would have to manually read the image list and draw the images onto the canvas yourself, along with all other possible drawing scenarios. If you want an example, let me know and I can spend some time putting something together.

Comment: Not possible with the stock image list control of D7. You need 32bbp images, D7 creates the image list with device dependent bitmaps.